# Solution for $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 \theta}{\mathrm{d} t^2}+C\frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\mathrm{d} t}+K\theta-\frac{1}{2-4\cos\theta}=K\theta^*$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have written a computer program to solve a differential equation regarding a project that I'm working. But I would like to test it with an analytical answer by solving the following ODE (That is derived from a project specific simplified example):

Suppose $\theta$ depends on the time $t$. And $C,K, \theta^{*}$ are constants.

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 \theta}{\mathrm{d} t^2}+C\frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\mathrm{d} t}+K\theta-\frac{1}{2-4\cos\theta}=K\theta^*$$

I do know how to handle this one if the non linear part, $\frac{1}{2-4\cos\theta}$ is not there. But this one I'm struggling to solve.

Appreciate your help